# Time to axislabel in HH:MM:SS format from seconds in R

Tags: r, axis-labels, datetime-conversion

I'm new to R and programming in general. I have data with time in format "HH:MM:SS". For plotting purposes I converted it to seconds.

My problem now is how to convert the seconds in axis (x-axis in this case) labels back to this format in a such way that I can choose whether I want one second intervals, one minute intervals or one hour intervals or pretty much any user defined interval. Mostly 1, 15 or 30 seconds/minutes or 1,2 hours or a combination of these such as one minute and 30 seconds and also give these axis labels appropriate positions on the axis.

Open to any kinds of suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lubridate package

```
library(lubridate)
t<-seconds_to_period(5000)
parse_date_time(t,"HMS")
```

Comment: lubridate package was very useful. I came up with a pretty nice solution that suits my purposes. Thank you.